# Unable to add xfce theme from Downloads to Themes

Tags: xfce

So im having issues with moving a theme from my downloads folder to the Themes folder.

Its through /usr/share/themes

When i try to move it, i get "Permission Denied", ive also tried through Sudo and got the same result, wont let me move it there.

Any ideas?

Screenfetch info here: http://prntscr.com/8g262b

Comment: Did you use `Sudo` or `sudo`?

Comment: linux is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to move it to your `/usr/share/themes` directory, just make a new directory named `~/.themes` and put it there instead.

```
mkdir ~/.themes
```

This will be a hidden directory so you will need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files and directories in thunar. This directory will be found in your home directory and will act as `/usr/share/themes` for your user only and will not work for all other users.

Comment: @CameronChisholm awesome, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the icon to the left to mark it solved. Thanks!